# Threadlocal not working in Intellij within an Aspect

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, aspectj, thread-local, hibernate-filters

I have a multitenancy springboot (2.4.5) application - i store the tenantId in ThreadLocal storage. I have loadtime weaving enabled for the Hibernate filter.

[Link to springboot and multitenancy](https://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2020/10/17/multi-tenancy-with-spring-boot-part5/)

The flow, at a high level when a HTTP request comes in, is
servletfilter->TenantFilterAspect( when the transaction starts) -> REST Api.
The servletFiler sets the tenantId, which is accessed by the TenantFilterAspect, and then when the query is run in the REST api, hibernate  applies the tenant filter.

If i run the application from the command line, everything works as expected.
However if i run this from intellij (ultimate 2021.1), the threadlocal variable is null in the Aspect but correct in the REST API.

i.e i set it in the filter and immediately print the tenantId - it is correct - when printed in the aspect, it is incorrect, when printed in the REST API it is correct again.

```java
public class JwtAuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            /* Tenant ID hardcoded in the example */
               TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(2);
               SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            /* Print ThreadID and value of thread local here */
            /* thread local value is 2 */

            }
        } 
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

```java
@Aspect
public class TenantFilterAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution (* org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.SessionBuilderImpl.openSession(..))")
    public void openSession() {
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "openSession()", returning = "session")
    public void afterOpenSession(Object session) {
        if (session != null && Session.class.isInstance(session)) {
            Long currentTenant = TenantContext.getCurrentTenant(); 
            /* Thread ID is same as in the filter but thread local value is null */
            org.hibernate.Filter filter = ((Session) session).enableFilter("tenantFilter");
            filter.setParameter("tenantId", currentTenant);
        }
    }

}
```

```java
/* @Transactional is at the class level - transaction is started before it gets here */ 
@PostMapping("/invoices/getPage")
public PagingDTO getInvoices(@RequestBody PagingDTO request) {
   Long currentTenant = TenantContext.getCurrentTenant();
   /* Thread ID is same as in the filter & aspect and thread local value is 2 */
   .....
}
```

```java
public class TenantContext {
    private static ThreadLocal<Long> currentTenant = new InheritableThreadLocal<>();
    public static Long getCurrentTenant() {
        return currentTenant.get();
    }
    public static void setCurrentTenant(Long tenant) {
        currentTenant.set(tenant);
    }
}
```

The command line (with additional line feeds for readability) is

```
java
  -javaagent:/home/x/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.6/aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar
  -jar target/webacc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

In Intellij, the VM options has been set similarly

```
-javaagent:/home/x/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.6/aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar
```

Any help on this strange behaviour will be deeply appreaciated - i am sort of clueless here. In both cases, the load time weaving appears correct (logging in the aspect is working), except that in the IntelliJ case, accessing the Threadlocal returns NULL in the aspect

**

---

**Update 2**

**
I have added minimal code as requested to reproduce the issue at https://github.com/AnishJoseph/Threadlocal-Issue. Instructions are in the readme.

---

**Update 3**

Based on the superb analysis by kriegaex below i did some digging up on Spring classloading related to dev-tools.

[Link to Spring's Customizing restart loader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.devtools.restart.customizing-the-classload)

Now, the fix is fairly straigtforward - i put the aspect code in a different module and excluded that jar from the reload. Now everything works perfectly.

Comment: I have spring secutity enabled - I tried accessing SecurityContextHolder.getContext() - this also shows up as null. I tried this as SecurityContextHolder also uses ThreadLocal. So looks like the threadlocal is available before the aspect and after the aspect, but not within the aspect

Comment: Interesting question, but I would like to reproduce the problem. Please provide a minimal Maven project on GitHub. I also use IntelliJ IDEA, so I should be able to reproduce both the command line and the IDEA situation. My assumption is that one or more things you explained differ from reality.

Comment: added the link to the maven project to the original post

Comment: That was not a clickable link, it was a clone URL. I fixed that for you. Be more careful next time, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem in IDEA. The reason seems to be the difference in how you start the application in both cases,

- from an executable JAR (command line) vs.
- from a classpath generated by the IDE as determined by Maven import.

If you compare the console logs in both cases, you see

- in the former case that the ApsectJ weaver is registered exactly once on a `LaunchedURLClassLoader`, while
- in the latter case it is registered 3x, first on an `AppClassLoader`, then `RestartClassLoader`, then `MethodUtil`.

I am not a Spring expert, so I do not know how Spring Boot fires up the application in the latter case, but I think that this difference in class-loading is the root cause of the problem. A workaround is to create a "JAR Application" type run configuration in IntelliJ IDEA and run the application that way. It behaves like from the console in that case, but of course you must make sure that the JAR is actually being built before starting it.

If I find out more, I will update the answer, but maybe this helps you a bit already.

---

**Update:** If you add `System.out.println("### " + TenantContext.class.getClassLoader());` in all 3 places, you will see this console log for the executable JAR:

```
### org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@53e25b76
In Servlet Filter : Thread ID is 21  :: ThreadLocal Value is 10
### org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@53e25b76
In TenantFilterAspect :: Thread ID is 21  :: ThreadLocal Value is 10
### org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@53e25b76
In REST API :: Thread ID is 21  :: ThreadLocal Value is 10
```

When starting the application from the IDE, however, you will see:

```
### org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@1c5e93fb
In Servlet Filter : Thread ID is 36  :: ThreadLocal Value is 10
### sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
In TenantFilterAspect :: Thread ID is 36  :: ThreadLocal Value is null
### org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@1c5e93fb
In REST API :: Thread ID is 36  :: ThreadLocal Value is 10
```

See? The `TenantContext` is loaded in two different classloaders, which means that there are two different thread-locals, which also explains why the one in the aspect is uninitialised.

---

**Update 2:** OK, I looked at the javadoc for [`RestartClassLoader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/devtools/restart/classloader/RestartClassLoader.html) and found this sentence:

> Disposable `ClassLoader` used to support application restarting. Provides parent last loading for the specified URLs.

**Parent last loading!** This is not what we want, because it means that each child classloader will reload classes the parent already has loaded before, which explains the problem we saw above. In order to get the consistent behaviour you expect, simply **deactivate this dependency** in your POM:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

This way you lose the ability to restart the application and dynamically refresh resources, but your tenant thingy works as expected. Please decide for yourself, which way you prefer. Maybe there is a way to configure the class-loading behaviour in a more fine-grained way, e.g. excluding `TenantContext` from parent-last loading. Not being a Spring user, I do not know.

By the way, you can also deactivate AspectJ Maven plugin, because the load-time weaver can finish the aspect while loading it, the compiler is not necessary for LTW, if you are not using native AspectJ syntax. The old plugin version you are using limits you to JDK 8. If you just remove it, you can also build your application with JDK 9+, e.g. JDK 16. I tested it, it works flawlessly.

Comment: Please also note my two updates, if you read the answer before. The second update solves your problem. That was a tricky, but interesting puzzle, wow!

Comment: Wow - thanks. I would never have imagined this was a classloader issue - i would have assumed a thread is a thread and its behaviour would be the same w.r.t threadlocal, regardless of the classloader. I dont know enough about classloaders to fully appreciate  and understand your solution, but it works - i guess i need to read up a lot more.

Comment: It is completely unrelated to threads. Any other static field would be affected in the same way. But a thought similar to your statement "a thread is a thread" is what made me think of other reasons. It had to be about how the application was started, threading could not be the issue because the 3 log lines are written in the very same thread. 

Comment: This was a very enlightening excercise. Anyways for now, i am going wilth disabling the plugin, as it only take 4 secs for me to reload. If i do find a better way i will post it here for others.

Comment: I have updated the original post to describe what needs to be done with the spring dev-tools setup to avoid this problem

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the update. Now we see a more complete picture. Like I speculated: _"Maybe there is a way to configure the class-loading behaviour in a more fine-grained way, e.g. excluding TenantContext from parent-last loading."_ Per-module granularity is fine, if you are free to restructure your application a bit.